# Why doesn't my nested class satisfy my protocol requirements?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol definition in a playground:

```
protocol Outer {
    associatedtype Nested: Inner

    protocol Inner {
        var property: String { get set }
    }
}
```

And the following implementation:

```
class Test: Outer {
    class Nested: Outer.Inner {
        var property: String = ""
    }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
Playground execution failed: error: nested protocols.playground:7:11: error: type 'Test.Nested' does not conform to protocol 'Inner'
    class Nested: Outer.Inner {
          ^

nested protocols.playground:8:13: note: candidate has non-matching type 'String'
        var property: String = ""
            ^
```

[Searching for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+candidate+has+non-matching+type) brought up solutions that I figure would work if my types actually didn't match, but as far as I know, a `String` is a `String`. **So what's going on here? Why isn't my property satisfying the protocol requirements?**

Comment: I get the error message "Protocol 'Inner' cannot be nested inside another declaration", which is probably the main issue here ;)

Comment: This was just as illegal in Swift 2 btw, the error message was just "type not allowed here" instead. I've therefore edited out the [swift3] tag, which is only for questions *directly* related to changes in the language for that version, and should only really be used as a supplemental tag to [swift] anyway (compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321824/2976878).

Comment: Like Hamish said, you can't nest protocols I guess.

Comment: Ugh I hate how Swift Playgrounds somehow have different errors than Projects. Thanks, @Hamish

Comment: I would simply advise not using them @BenLeggiero – they're super buggy and unreliable. Working in a main.swift file of an Xcode project is a far better way of testing Swift behaviour, as it allows you to write top-level code without the headaches that playgrounds bring (the macOS command line tool template is good for this).